# Is it possible to use Java EE JPA @Query together with @EntityGraph?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying lazy fetch JPA entities like described in [How to load lazy fetched items from Hibernate/JPA in my controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359306/how-to-load-lazy-fetched-items-from-hibernate-jpa-in-my-controller) That post in the example uses two classes - `Person` and `Role` and Person entity has associated roles.

I need to fetch roles for each person, but I need to fetch only some persons not all the persons. So - can I use `@Query` and `@EntityGraph` on the the same method of repository?

Comment: You should be able to, according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40084261/251542