# how to modify object with @ManyToOne relationship in Spring boot + rest

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

this is my region class :

```
    @Entity(name = "REGION")

public class Region {

    private Long id;
    private String region;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Compagnie.class, mappedBy = "region", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Compagnie> compagnie;
```

this is my Compagnie class :

```
@Entity(name = "COMPAGNIE")
public class Compagnie {

    private Long id;
    private String compagnie;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "REGION_ID")
    private Region region;
```

this is my edit method from controller class :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/compagnie/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getCompagnie(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    logger.info("Fetching Compagnie with id {}", id);
    Compagnie compagnie = compagnieRepository.findOne(id);
    if (compagnie == null) {
        logger.error("Compagnie with id {} not found.", id);
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Unable to update. Compagnie with id " + id + " not found."),
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Compagnie>(compagnie, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the json that i use for test is :

**{
  "compagnie": "test compagnie 1",
  "region": {
    "id": 1,
    "region": "region 1"
  }
}**

the compagnie change but the region wont and i cant be able to read the region attributes from the @requestBody .

i really need your help .
thanks .

Comment: I think you should get the Object graph automatically since you've an object relationship. Please see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943989/spring-data-jpa-and-namedentitygraphs

Answer (score 0):

The `Region` is not fetched in that case by default by your persistence provider.

Define entity graph details on the entity:

```
@Entity(name = "COMPAGNIE")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Compagnie.region",
  attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("region"))
public class Compagnie {
```

Then override the definition of the `findOne` method in your jpa repository interface:

```
public interface CompagnieRepository extends JpaRepository<Compagnie, String> {

    @EntityGraph("Compagnie.region")
    Compagnie findOne(Long id);
}
```

Now the dependency will be fetched eagerly and region data should be present in the response body.