# Spring Data JPA, parametrize @EntityGraph in CrudRepository interface

Tags: spring, jpa, entitygraph

Is it possible with Spring Data JPA to do smth. like this:

```
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

@EntityGraph(value = :graphName, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u")
    List<User> findAllWithDetailsByGraphName(@Param(value="graphName") String graphName);

}
```

to be able to pass the graphName into method at run-time and invoke the load with a need set of collections? This construction is not working, producing compile time error. Any plays around it also failed...

So, I have multiple collections in User class, which I want to load on condition;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.details", attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("phones"), @NamedAttributeNode("emails"), @NamedAttributeNode("pets")}),
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.phones", attributeNodes =
                {@NamedAttributeNode("phones")}),
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.emails", attributeNodes =
                {@NamedAttributeNode("emails")}),
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.pets", attributeNodes =
                {@NamedAttributeNode("pets")})
})
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

// more fields omitted

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Phone> phones;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Email> emails;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Pet> pets;
}
```

Now, I only must declare all the methods implicitly, like this:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "User.phones", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u")
List<User> findAllWithPhones();
```

Thnaks you for suggestions!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA And NamedEntityGraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943989/spring-data-jpa-and-namedentitygraphs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a base JPA repository that accepts the entity graph as a parameter. This is particularly useful in combination with `Specification`s. Therefore, here follows an example based on `Specification`s. It's also possible to construct other queries, using different types of arguments.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyBaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

    T findOne(Specification<T> spec, EntityGraphType entityGraphType, String entityGraphName);

    List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Sort sort, EntityGraphType entityGraphType, String entityGraphName);

}
```

Implement the base repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class MyBaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements MyBaseRepository<T, ID> {

    private EntityManager em;

    public MyBaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.em = entityManager;
    }

    public MyBaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public T findOne(Specification<T> spec, EntityGraph.EntityGraphType entityGraphType, String entityGraphName) {
        TypedQuery<T> query = getQuery(spec, (Sort) null);
        query.setHint(entityGraphType.getKey(), em.getEntityGraph(entityGraphName));
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Sort sort, EntityGraph.EntityGraphType entityGraphType, String entityGraphName) {
        TypedQuery<T> query = getQuery(spec, sort);
        query.setHint(entityGraphType.getKey(), em.getEntityGraph(entityGraphName));
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Specify the custom base repository:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="my.domain" base-class="my.repository.MyBaseRepositoryImpl" />
```

Extend from custom base repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, MyBaseRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

Use the custom repository's method:

```
Specification mySpecs = ...
List<User> user = picklistRepository.findAll(mySpecs, EntityGraphType.LOAD, "User.phones");
```