# Spring Data JPA findAll with different EntityGraph

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, entitygraph

in Spring Data JPA Repository i need to specify multiple methods that do the same thing (eg. findAll) but specifying different @EntityGraph annotation (the goal is to have optimized methods to use in different services).

Es.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>, JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "roles" })
findAll[withRoles](Specification sp);

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "groups" })
findAll[withGroups](Specification sp);

etc...
}
```

In Java we can't have same method sign multiple times, so how to manage it?

Is it possible without using JPQL?

Thanks,

Gabriele

Comment: You can use an ```EntityGraph``` as a parameter : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949656/spring-data-jpa-parametrize-entitygraph-in-crudrepository-interface

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know you could pass the entity graph as a parameter! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor` to pass different `entitygraph` based on your method.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>, JpaRepository<User, Long>, EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

}
```

In your service class, you can call find all with entity graph.

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findAll(specification, new NamedEntityGraph(EntityGraphType.FETCH, "graphName"))
```

Like above, you can use a different entity graph different based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has been very useful to me. Thanks!

Comment: You can accept the answer so that others know the same

Comment: I can't seem to find `EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor`, where did you get it from?

Comment: @La Hai, You need to add dependency for it from `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cosium.spring.data/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph/2.4.2`

Answer (score 0):

You can create two default methods in your repository with same signature like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<User>, JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "roles" })
    default List<Roles> findAllByRoles(Specification sp){
       return findAll(sp);
    }

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "groups" })
    default List<Roles> findAllByGroups(Specification sp){
       return findAll(sp);
    }
}
```