# @EntityGraph annotation doesn't work properly?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

I need to implement two different implementations for the same `findAll()` method by following different EntityGraphs annotations. By referencing through another StackOverflow post, I found a way to implement the same `findAll()` method with different EntityGrpahs. But when I use default methods as mentioned in that post, I am not getting the expected behavior. It neglects the `@EntityGraph` annotation and returns lazy Collections by following the default behavior.
Please provide a fix for this issue or state any other better solution that I can implement to solve this problem.

```
public interface BspCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<DbpMetaBspCategory, String> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"dbpBspMetaCollection","dbpBspMetaCollection.dbpBspMetaCustomFieldCollection","dbpBspMetaCollection.bspType","dbpBspMetaCollection.bankCode","dbpBspMetaCollection.dbpBspMetaCustomFieldCollection.fieldType"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)

    default List<DbpMetaBspCategory> findAllCategories(){
      return findAll();
    }


}
```

Please refer to the second answer in the post which was answered by Femi.
[References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943989/spring-data-jpa-and-namedentitygraphs)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data simply can not know about this annotation, as the method is not abstract. You should be able to declare the method just like this:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"dbpBspMetaCollection","dbpBspMetaCollection.dbpBspMetaCustomFieldCollection","dbpBspMetaCollection.bspType","dbpBspMetaCollection.bankCode","dbpBspMetaCollection.dbpBspMetaCustomFieldCollection.fieldType"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
List<DbpMetaBspCategory> findAllCategories();
```